# UDF to extract specific data from a generic string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function like =Extractinfo("A2","Name"), which can extract name, phone and email id from raw data, one function for all 3 extractions, I already have a function to extract email id

```
 Raw Data

"Name":"Ram","Phone":"9898989898","Email":"abcd@gmail.com"
"Name":"Raju","Phone":"2323232323","Email":"xyz123@gmail.com"
"Name":"Rameshsing","Phone":"555999999","Email":"rameshsing@gmail.com"

(Function to extract)          (Expected Result)
=Extractinfo("A2","Name")      Ram
=Extractinfo("A2","Name")      Raju
=Extractinfo("A4","Name")      Rameshsing


Function ExtractEmailFun(extractStr As String) As String

 Dim CharList As String
 On Error Resume Next
CheckStr = "[A-Za-z0-9._-]"
OutStr = ""
Index = 1
Do While True
Index1 = VBA.InStr(Index, extractStr, "@")
getStr = ""
If Index1 > 0 Then
    For p = Index1 - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(extractStr, p, 1) Like CheckStr Then
            getStr = Mid(extractStr, p, 1) & getStr
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    getStr = getStr & "@"
    For p = Index1 + 1 To Len(extractStr)
        If Mid(extractStr, p, 1) Like CheckStr Then
            getStr = getStr & Mid(extractStr, p, 1)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Index = Index1 + 1
    If OutStr = "" Then
        OutStr = getStr
    Else
        OutStr = OutStr & Chr(10) & getStr
    End If
Else
      Exit Do
End If
Loop
ExtractEmailFun = OutStr
End Function
```

Comment: What is your overall goal, and what is the source of the data?  If your goal is to create a table, then `Power Query` can do this fairly easily.  If you need the items separated for some other reason, Regular Expressions is one way to approach.

Comment: If your data is in JSON format then there are better ways to approach this.

Comment: Are these strings in a cell? And are the entries all of the form "Name":"Ram","Phone":"9898989898","Email":"abcd@gmail.com"

Comment: Yes it's JSON format and its in one cell from where I'm trying to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Public Function ExtractInfo(s As String, choice As String) As String

    dq = Chr(34)
    arr = Split(s, dq)

    If choice = "Name" Then
        ExtractInfo = arr(3)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If choice = "Phone" Then
        ExtractInfo = arr(7)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If choice = "Email" Then
        ExtractInfo = arr(11)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ExtractInfo = "bad data"
End Function
```

[image]

This assumes that all your data follows the same schema.  Options would be:

```
=extractinfo(A1,"Name")
=extractinfo(A1,"Phone")
=extractinfo(A1,"Email")
```

You could also use `Case` for this.

Comment: it's working perfectly, this is what i was looking than you so much

Answer (score 2):

Your RAW data seems to match the JSON format. One thing that can be done is to use a module (like [this one](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) that worked very well for me) to parse it (i.e. put some order in it, so you can easily get the result you are looking for).

Follow the [simple instructions](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON#installation) to add this module to your VBA project (remember to add the Microsoft.Scripting Reference!). Then your function would look like this :

```
Public Function Extractinfo(byval CompleteString as String, byval FieldName as String) as String

    Dim JSON as Object
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(CompleteString)

    ExtractInfo = JSON(FieldName)

End Function
```

This code sample is overly simplified (does not have any error handling), but this should get you started.